# View the function of external py files in the textbox (while the function is running)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

This is a graphics window that scrapes and shows any errors across icons. There are two scrapings scripts (msg1 and msg2) that are recalled from other py files, more precisely their scraping functions (Selenium) are recalled. Scraping is done correctly,

i would like to view the scraping in a textbox, so i would like to view what happens in the python console in the textbox. What I would like to display in the textobox are msg1 and msg2 (which would be the two scraping py files). I add that I would like to display the scraping during its scraping (in live), and not at the end of the function: while the function is running

How can I view msg1 and msg2 in the textobox?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

from File import Scraping_Nome_Campionati
from File import Scraping_Nome_Squadre_MIO

from File.Scraping_Nome_Campionati import scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor
from File.Scraping_Nome_Squadre_MIO import scraping_nome_squadre_e_tor


def draw_graph():
    test_scraping=tk.Toplevel()
    test_scraping.title("aaaa")
    test_scraping.geometry("1100x900")
    test_scraping.configure(bg='#282828')

    def do_scraping():
        #Start the scraping functions of the two py files and search for errors 
        #msg1 and msg2 recall the two scraping py files, because they check for scraping errors by showing the green icon and the red icon
        msg1 = Scraping_Nome_Campionati.scraping_nome_campionati_e_tor()
        if msg1:
            message1.configure(text=msg1)
            message1.configure(foreground="red")
            vuoto_elenco_campionati.config(image=render7)
    
        else:
            vuoto_elenco_campionati.config(image=render8)
            message1.configure(foreground="green")


        msg2 = Scraping_Nome_Squadre_MIO.scraping_nome_squadre_e_tor()
        if msg2:
            message2.configure(text=msg2)
            message2.configure(foreground="red")
            vuoto_elenco_squadre.config(image=render7)

        else:
            vuoto_elenco_squadre.config(image=render8)
            message2.configure(foreground="green")


    text = tk.Text(test_scraping,width=80,height=50,  background="black", foreground="white")
    text.pack()
    text.place(x=450, y=20)


    button = Button(test_scraping, text="Avvia", bg='#e95420', foreground='white', command=do_scraping)
    button.place(x=116, y=512)
```

Comment: put in a thread and use a queue to communicate with the main thread (could use multiprocessing too) then have a sort of update function (that uses `.after()` method) to get data from queue and insert it in widgets

Comment: @matiiss Could you show me the answer with the code please? I didn't understand much. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example using `multiprocessing` module:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Text
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty
import time


def update_text(widget, queue):
    try:
        data = queue.get(block=False)
        if data == '--END--':
            return
    except Empty:
        pass
    else:
        widget.insert('end', data)
    root.after(100, update_text, widget, queue)


def do_in_parallel_1(queue):
    for i in range(10):
        queue.put(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    queue.put('--END--')


def do_in_parallel_2(queue):
    for i in range(10, 20):
        queue.put(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    queue.put('--END--')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()

    queue1 = Queue()
    text1 = Text()
    text1.pack()
    update_text(text1, queue1)
    Process(target=do_in_parallel_1, args=(queue1,)).start()

    queue2 = Queue()
    text2 = Text()
    text2.pack()
    update_text(text2, queue2)
    Process(target=do_in_parallel_2, args=(queue2,)).start()

    root.mainloop()
```

---

**IMPORTANT**
place all your executable code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` block because when creating new processes, it basically creates a copy and executes everything in there which can cause issues and actually will raise an error.

---

**Side note:** the time module is just for the demonstration

**Update function:**
First define an "update" function in this case the `update_text()` function. What it does is simply first `try:` to get data from the queue (and `if data == '--END--': return` which basically stops this function once the process has finished (if all is set up correctly)) it has an argument `block` which is set to `False` which basically means that if there is nothing in the `Queue` then proceed however this raises the `Empty` exception which gets handled by the `except Empty:` and it basically does nothing, so if there is an exception it just uses `root.after()` to call this function again (loop) in 100 ms (such "loops" don't block `.mainloop()`), however if there was no exception then also update the passed widget (which in this case should be the `tkinter.Text` widget)

**Now the other two functions:**
Well they are super simple and also basically identical (one just puts different numbers in the queue) but basically what you have to understand is that while the function is running you should put the data you want to appear on `Text` widgets in the `Queue` using the `.put()` method, however when the function finished, right before that you should `.put()` the "flag" that will tell the "update" function that the process is finished and they will all stop (not waste resources)

**The part where it all actually starts:**
This happens inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` (obviously you can define other functions outside just don't call them outside (unless in another function) because anything that is called from outside anything gets executed by all the processes too)
So now two, identical processes (could use a loop but there are just two so no need really), first initiate a `Queue` class: `queue1 = Queue()` then create a text widget, then pack it, then start the `update_text()` function (also pass in the arguments), then start the process `Process(target=do_in_parallel_1, args=(queue1,)).start()` (at first I wondered why it didn't work and noticed finally that I hadn't `start()`ed the processes) and then just repeat that for the other function.

**Misc**
Basically for you instead of `do_in_parallel_n()` functions you will have your scraping function but the principle is the same, just remember to put `queue.put()` there and inside the object you want to pass (the scraped thing or sth)

**Useful sources:**

- [Python Multiprocessing Tutorial: Run Code in Parallel Using the Multiprocessing Module by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU)
- [Communication Between Processes](https://bip.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/multiprocessing/communication.html)
- [About the `.after()` method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/)

*If you have any questions - feel free to ask!*

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, but I didn't quite understand how I could use it with my question code. I am new to Python and have never used the multiprocessing module, so I would be a bit confused. Sorry if I disturb you, but could you show me in the reply (maybe by creating an upload 2 of your answer) how to apply my code to it? Thank you

Comment: @JamesD.Com see there are two functions: `do_in_parallel_1` and `do_in_parallel_2` so what you gotta do is replace them with your functions, that simple (obviously then change the name everywhere), and wherever you are expecting to get sth from scraping, put a queue and place the expected string or whatever into that queue (don't forget to add the queue argument)

Comment: @JamesD.Com ok, put in your question (edit and put somewhere at the bottom) a standalone scraping function, then I can adjust it for you, also read carefuly what I wrote and the kind of issue is that if You don't understand, then it means in this case at least that you should first understand it, ok, I put some sources in the answer so you can use those to help yourself understand parts of the code

Comment: Thank you. I'll try tomorrow and I'll let you know. Now it's late. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, but I can't apply it to the code I posted in the question, because my code is a bit particular: I have a function (do_scraping) that calls two other functions (of external py files). You have been very kind, but I can't. Could you upload 2 of your answer and merge my code with yours? I would appreciate very much. Thank you and excuse me. I will vote and accept your answer

Comment: @JamesD.Com ok, can you edit those functions? or at least view them or sth like that, so that You can show them in your question and then I can show You how to do that on those particular functions.